# How can I use: x in {1,2,4,5,7,8} in Alloy?

Tags: alloy

I am a Alloy beginner!

I want to perform, example like this:

```
run {all x: {2,3,4,5}, y: {1,2,3,4} | x > y and x + y <=10}
```

How can I solve above constraint in **Alloy**?

Thank so much!

D.M

Answer (score 4):

You can add constraints to enforce that the given property should hold if the value of x and y are in the interval you want them to be.

Also, you need to pay attention the + operator is used for set union.
If `x=4` and `y=5`, then `x+y` will yield : `{4,5}` . You need to call the `add[x,y]` built in function to perform an addition.

To summarize, here is your constraint.

```
   run {all x,y:Int | (x >1 and x <6 and y > 0 and y <5 ) implies  x > y and add[x,y] <=10} for 5 Int
```

Note the `for 5 Int` at the end of the command, It tells the analyzer that it should consider in its analysis Integers that can be represented within 5 bits, i.e. [-16,15]

Note also that this predicate is inconsistent as you request that all combination of integers in the interval [-16,15] satisfy the given condition.

**EDIT**

You can actually declare "variables" in Alloy using let. (both inside another structure for local variable and outside for global variable)

In your example, you could write :

```
let X= 2+3+6+8+12+17+18+20
let Y= 3+5+6+8+10
```

remembering that + is a set union operator

Your command could then be :

```
run {all x :X,y:Y |  x > y and add[x,y] <=10} for 6 Int.
```

Note that the same comments apply to this command (i.e. it is inconsistent)

Comment: It's very useful for me. I want to ask another case: if the set of any integer values, e.g x: {2,3,6,8, 12, 17, 18,20}, and y: {3,5, 6, 8, 10}? How do we solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation. I am really appreciate!

Comment: my pleasure, feel free to accept the answer so that we know this question has been taken care of :-)